# Parameterise SQL Stored Procedure Excel Get&Transform

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to call a stored select procedure from SQL Server into Excel.

In SSMS could be written as

```
@val1=1;
@val2=2;
Execute SP_DoStuff(@param1=@val1,@param2=@val2);
```

Looking at similar questions, a common answer is to concatenate the parameter and run as dynamic SQL. For example:
[Use values in cells as parameters in stored procedure in power query editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428331/use-values-in-cells-as-parameters-in-stored-procedure-in-power-query-editor)

The answer there is

```
Source = Sql.Database("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", [Query=
"#(lf)#(lf)EXEC#(tab) [dbo].[TestParameter]#(lf)
#(tab)#(tab)@from = '" & YourDateMethod & "'#(lf)
#(tab)#(tab)@isValid = 1,#(lf)
#(tab)#(tab)@someInt = 90"
]) 
in Source
```

Unless I'm missing something here, this established method looks wide open to injection due to string concatenation of YourDateMethod.

Is there a method to feed values from Excel into the parameters safely?

For example odbc allows preparing with tokens

```
Execute SP_DoStuff(@param1=?,@param2=?);
```

Then feed in ? as values at runtime

Comment: Maybe using VBA instead. The power query approach always use concatenation, like this one https://reevessmith.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/power-query-and-stored-procedures-with-parameters/

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492612/6241235)

Comment: Worth noting that if you are using Excel to connect to a SQL database in general you are inherently open to anything. Excel is not a secure environment and anyone with the knowledge or interest to manipulate a SQL database would easily be able to utilize any arrangement in Excel that is connecting to one. Your goal with Excel is generally to prevent users from being able to accidentally screw anything up, as opposed to acting maliciously.

Comment: Thanks guys. 

@Wedge
Agreed that there's no entirely safe way to do this relying on Excel. Even using parameters the end user can still edit the query or obtain plaintext credentials.

This is a case where least-privileges security looks like the best solution. In the end I heavily limited the SQL user and used string concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Value.NativeQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/value-nativequery) to write parameterized queries. For example, if you wanted a query that only showed columns with the name Alice, you could do

`Value.NativeQuery(Sql.Database("server", "database"), "select Name from Employees where Name = @myName", [ myName = "Alice" ])`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.

You've got an extra bracket after "database"), can you please edit? I'm unable to make minor edits of 6-or-less characters.