# how to pass parameters to a sql query from power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

It is possible to pass parameters for a query that in powe query ?

If possible can you give me an example?

```
Select * from Products Where IdProduct = ????
```

How to pass parameter to this statement ?

Comment: You may find the answer here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: No sabes leer no vez que lo que pregunto ? estamos hablando de Power Query no de SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterise SQL Stored Procedure Excel Get&Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761920/parameterise-sql-stored-procedure-excel-gettransform)